# I used chown from SSh and now i can't access ftp anymore

Tags: magento2

I run the command `chown -R root:1003 .` in SSH and now when I try to connect to FTP it says Access Denied, what should I do to fix this problem ? The `1003` it's the group code for my `httpacces` folder. The `httpacces` is the location where I installed my Magento2 and I tried to make user *root* the owner of all folders and sub folders, the problem is that I can't access FTP even with *root*.

Answer (score 0):

What's your web user? The files should be owned by this user.

e.g. if web user is www-data, you'd type this within the Magento root directory.

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .`

N.B, you shouldn't be using the `root` user for FTP (or ssh), create a `sudo` account and create your web apps via that.

Comment: How i check my web user?

Comment: Apache or nginx? if apache try `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`

Comment: When i use the command given Putty shows this: https://imgur.com/YqL5xQR ---> What to do now?

Comment: that shows your web user is apache. So try `chown -R apache:apache .`

Comment: Ok so i used "cd /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs" (httpdocs it's the directory where i installed Magento2, and then used "chown -R apache:apache ." but the problem persists, when I try to connect to FTP i get this error: https://imgur.com/a/I30kCMz

Comment: Looks like your ftp is trying to default to the / directory? instead of /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro so check your vsftp configs. Also add your user 'ecustock' to the 'apache' group `usermod -a -G apache ecustock`

Comment: Can we talk on skype please? I can't figure it out...